# Лексический анализ строки на Паскале

Tags: строки, pascal

```
Program opn;
     uses crt;
    const
       inp=('Введите строчку, преобразованную в опн ');
       outp=('Результат равен ');
       sp=#32;
       err=('Ошибка: ');
var
   el:array[1..128] of elements;
   e,x,i,k:integer;
   ch1,ch2:real;
   s,d:string;
   stack:PElement;
begin
   stack:=nil;
   e:=0;
   x:=0;
   i:=0;
   k:=0;
   s:='';
   d:='';
   ch1:=0;
   ch2:=0;
   writeln(inp);
   read(s);
    for i:=1 to length(s) do       {начало классификации}
       with el[i] do
           begin
               k:=pos(sp,s);
               d:=copy(s,1,k-1);
               val(d,x,e);
               if (e=0) then
                   num:=x
               else
                   op:=d[1];
               delete(s,1,k);
           end;                            {конец классификации}

{здесь вроде как нормально но дальше ошибки выдает, при взятии элементов}
for i:=1 to length(el) do
       if el[i] in num then Push(el[i]);
       if el[i] in op then
           begin
               case op of
               '+': 
                begin
                    ch1:= pop(stack);
                    ch2:= pop(stack);
                    ch1:= ch1 + ch2;
                    push(ch1);
                end;      {и так же остальные операции}
```

ссылки на весь [код](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9x6v7u0t2hxagr/OPN_NORM.pas) 
вывод компилятора

```
Сompiling your program...

prog.pas(99,36) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "elements", expected "SmallInt"
prog.pas(102,24) Error: Identifier not found "op"
prog.pas(103,19) Error: Constant and CASE types do not match
prog.pas(108,26) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Real", expected "SmallInt"
prog.pas(110,19) Error: Constant and CASE types do not match
prog.pas(115,26) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Real", expected "SmallInt"
prog.pas(117,19) Error: Constant and CASE types do not match
prog.pas(122,26) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Real", expected "SmallInt"
prog.pas(124,19) Error: Constant and CASE types do not match
prog.pas(136,28) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Real", expected "SmallInt"
prog.pas(139,19) Error: Constant and CASE types do not match
prog.pas(144,26) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Real", expected "SmallInt"
prog.pas(100,13) Error: Boolean expression expected, but got "Char"
prog.pas(148,4) Fatal: There were 13 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppc386 returned an error exitcode (normal if you did not specify a source file to be compiled)
```

не могу понять, почему компилятор ругается на взятие элемента из массива

Comment: И каков вопрос?

Comment: @alexlz действительно -______- прощу прощения,не могу понять, почему компилятор ругается на взятие элемента из массива._. в частности на case op

Comment: Не смог посмотреть вывод Вашего компилятора (его можно было и в вопрос включить -- кучу кода Вы включили).

Ошибки: 

Строка 50 (ф. pop) -- не определён идентификатор Item. Компилятор 100% прав.

Стр. 63 (функция raise) -- не сбалансированы скобки).

Увы...

Comment: @alexlz  скобку добавил в raise, согласен, косяк._. но все же, мне как исправить item в 50-ой строчке? Плюс, правильно ли я организовал классификацию элементов? ну вроде как да._. тип записи, два поля. Но вот при отборе элементов фигня._. но я брал способ из множества._. " if el[i] in num then ..."

Comment: А что Вы хотели от 50 строки? Если вернуть это значение из функции pop, то строка д.б.

    Pop := TopPointer^.Item;

Поскольку никаких return'ов там нет. Ежели я ещё не совсем паскаль забыл. Ну а дальше у Вас ещё ошибки. Изучайте язык, исправляйте ошибки

Comment: @alexlz реализацию стека брал [отсюда][1] ._. единственное толковое объяснение динамической памяти , которое я нашел в интернете. Функции, соответственно, там тоже приведены._.


[1]: http://altim.narod.ru/Docs/Russian/Manuals/Lab/Chapter2/DataStructures.htm

Comment: @Mayhem, даже если исправить синтаксические ошибки, код работать не будет.
у вас код стека никак не относится к вашей программе. например:

 * `pop(stack)` и что по-вашему должно происходить (ну кроме того, что у `pop` вовсе нет параметров)? 
 * что у вас в стеке хранится и почему pop у вас должен вдруг вернуть real?
 * что такое `op` в вашем `case`'е? нет таких переменных (подсказка: из блока `with` вы вышли чуть раньше).

Comment: Я бы посоветовал оттестить сначала стек, разобраться как он работает (без копипасты), потом что-нибудь пытаться в него полезное писать. Начинать можно разбираться с того что за переменные `TopPointer` и `stack` и что вы от них хотите.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov на сколько я понял TopPointer и является самим стеком._. одновременно указателем на вершину._. а во с рор так и не разобрался( не понимаю алгоритма действия функции._. есть литература или интернет издания, где можно почитать и разобраться в этом? ну или мб кто напишет, как правильно реализовать нужные мне функции

Comment: @Mayhem, ну а тогда переменная `stack` вам зачем?  
ссылку вы сами привели. то, что там есть ошибка в коде не отменяет теории, которая там изложена. задача pop получить элемент на вершине стека и удалить его из стека, ничего сложного. возможно вам надо сначала на бытовом уровне понять что такое стек - это, например, стопка газет, на которую кладут новые газеты всегда наверх и берут газеты тоже сверху и тоже всегда.

в любом случае, код, который вы оттуда скопировали, без модификации вам не подойдет. как минимум из-за того, что там в стек кладутся элементы с Integer данными, а вам нужны Real.